# copy element of array

Tags: java, arrays

I can't figure out why isn't the code copying the unique elements to another array. Here is my code. I though that the `==` is to copy the element, but I got an error, so I used the `=` instead.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int[] B = new int[15];
    B[2] = 2;
    B[3] = 3;
    B[4] = 4;
    B[5] = 5;
    B[6] = 6;
    B[7] = 7;
    B[8] = 8;
    B[9] = 9;
    B[10] = 10;

    int[] check = new int[B.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < B.length; i++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < check.length; x++) {
            if (B[i] != check[x]) {
                check[x] = B[i];
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < check.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(check[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`==` is for test of equalation,`=` is for assignment,

by the way ,use `System.arraycopy(xxx)` to copy arrays.

```
public int[] findUnique(int[] data) {
    int[] unique = new int[data.length];
    int x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        boolean uni = true;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < data.length; j++) {
            if (data[i] == data[j]) {
                uni = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (uni) {
            unique[x++] = data[i];
        }
    }
    return unique;
}
```

Comment: can i use it just to copy one element?

Comment: What are you going to achive?

Comment: You mean removing duplicated items from the array?

Comment: yes that's is what is getting me confused in this . the teacher said we have to loop through the array twice . once to find the unique items and another to copy it over. im not sure what he means by this

Answer (score 2):

You're looping over everything twice, when it should just be once.

Currently it looks like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < B.length; i++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < B.length; x++) {
        if (B[i] != check[x]) {
            check[x] = B[i];
        }
    }
}
```

This means that `when i = 0 , then x=0, 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.. .` Then `when i = 1, x=0,1,2,3.... , etc.`

So the last run will be `i=14`, where `B[i] = 0`.
So for every `check[x]`, it won't be equal to `0`.

What you want to do is handle it in a line. So instead of 2 variables `i` and `x` you can just use `i` and the outer loop, like this. This means that you're only comparing `B[1] to check[1] and B[2] to check[2]`, and so on.

Like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < B.length; i++) {
    if (B[i] != check[i]) {
        check[i] = B[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: that wasn't what I meant, I'll try to clarify

Comment: @brianChiem, Let's consider what you're doing here - you're trying to copy elements of `B` to `check`, right? Now, you have set `B`'s size to 15, which means that apart from the values at indices you've specified, Java would fall back to default values for the primitive type you've specified - In this case, int - 0. So, you're mutating `check` over and over again, losing previous changes.

Comment: but if you do it your say. if b[1] and b[5] = 9 then check[1] = 9 won't check [5] equal 9 also?

Comment: i am trying not to get any duplicates in the array

Answer (score 0):

[System.arrayCopy()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy%28java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int%29) is much faster